# minimizing the maximum hundai by replacing it with bmw

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

we have given two arrays **H[ ]** and **B[ ]** both of size **n**.
**H[i]** denotes number of hundai car the **(i)th** person have.
I have **'m'** BMW car,which I can replace with hundai. 
**B[i]** contain number of hundai car equivalent to **1** BMW(means for each person the equivalency may differ).
**Given:**

```
H[i]%B[i]=0;
```

The question is to **minimize** the **max(H[i])** by replacing it with BMW(note that we have only m BMW).
O(n) or O(nlogn) solution required.

Comment: if you want to minimize `max(H[i])` you find the index that contains the biggest number and subtract `B[i]`. and you do that in a loop, while you have BMWs left.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share **your** findings and code.

Comment: What I tried : I recognised it as greedy problem  and i tried to sort the H array and with a simple approach tried to reduce the maximum height till it no longer remains maximum and then found the new maximum and again applied the same steps, it's correct but it's too naive and taking huge amount of time for large values?

Time taking steps : finding maximum element each time O(N) and sorting is also not an option (every time).

Constraints for n are upto 10^5 and m are around 10^18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas revolving around `minimizing .. the maximum of ..` are approachable using a *binary search* I've answered a question along the same lines here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679263/10291310

For your case, we can modify the algorithm to,

```
start = 0, end = 10^18 // Or your max `M` limit
while start <= end:
    bmw_used = 0 // Number of bmws used till now for this iteration
    mid = (start + end) / 2
    // Let's see if its possible to lower down all the hyndais such
    // that number of each hundai <= mid
    for i in range(0,N):
        if H[i] > mid:
            // Calculate the number of bmws required to bring H[i] <= mid
            bmw_required = ceil(1.0 * (H[i] - mid) / B[i])
            bmw_used += bmw_required
    // After iterating over the Hyndais
    if bmw_used > M:
        // We're exceeding the number of bmws, hence increase the number of huyndai
        start = mid + 1
    else:
        // We still have some more bmws left, so let's reduce more hyndais
        end = mid - 1

return start
```

The total runtime complexity of the solution is *O(N*log(M))*. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man.It is really very helpful.I am trying with the same approach the asker of question does in link provided by u. I am even not thinking of log(M).we can make **end=H[n-1]** (which is max height ).

Answer (score 0):

**pseudocode**

```
for k = 1 to m
  max_i = 0
  for i = 1 to n-1
    if H[max_i] < H[i] then max_i = i
  if H[max_i] >= B[max_i] then H[max_i] -= B[max_i]
  else break
```

The total complexity is O(mn).
If you can ignore m, it will be O(n).
This algorithm may have some unnecessary loops when there are same H values, but it's not a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping.But this will not work because m is of range 10^18.